# Proving that the subspace on 2.2.1.d exercise of Kenneth Linear algebra is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

The exercise says as it follows:

Is the set of vectors with the shape $S = \{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n), a_1a_2=0 \}$ a subspace?

I started developing a proof by proving if $w = u + \alpha v \in S$. For that reason I got to the conclusion that if $w_1w_2 = 0$ then $v_1u_2 + v_2u_1 = 0$, but I don't know exactly how to continue with an analytical approach.

Of course, it is easy to find a case in which 2 vectors can be found in S whose sum isn't in S, but I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't go that pace.

Comment: "Of course, it is easy to find a case in which 2 vectors can be found in S whose sum isn't in S, but I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't go that pace." That's the easiest argument, why would you not be happy with this insight?

Answer (score 1):

Your subset is the union of two subspaces ("$a_1=0$",and "$a_2 = 0$") neither of them containing the other. In that case, the union is not a subspace.

Comment: Can you actually show that if you have two subspaces neither of them containing the other that the union is not a subspace without first showing that the sum of elements need not be interior in this case?

Comment: @Mathematician 42: I would just consider the sum $u_1 + u_2$, $u_i \in V_i \backslash V_{i+1}$.  The union is still closed under multiplication by scalars